# Conversion error from Dictionary<DateTime, KeyValuePair<DateTime, Business.Note>> to Dictionary<DateTime, List<Business.Note>>

Tags: c#, .net

This is my code:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Business.Note>> testData = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<Business.Note>>(); //code emitted for abbreviation on how this dictionary is filled up


 var groupedData = testData.GroupBy(d => {

    if (d.Key == today)
        return "Today";

    return "Other";
});



Dictionary<DateTime, List<Business.Note>> testData2 = groupedData.First().ToDictionary(g => g.Key); //this line gives compile time error
```

My final objective is to get `Dictionary<DateTime, List<Business.Note>>` inside testData2 but at the moment I get the error Cannot implicitly convert from `Dictionary<DateTime, KeyValuePair<DateTime, Business.Note>>` to `Dictionary<DateTime, List<Business.Note>>`

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `groupedData.First().ToDictionary` your dictionary now contains: `<DateTime, KeyValuePair<DateTime, Business.Note>`

As a result this line will cause compile error:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Business.Note>> testData2 = groupedData.First().ToDictionary(g => g.Key);
```

Because you cannot implicitly, or explicitly convert one type of dictionary to another.

---

You have two possible solutions here:

**1) remove the `.First()` and use only `.ToDictionary`**:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Business.Note>> testData2 = groupedData.ToDictionary(g => g.Key);
```

**2) Change the type of your dictionary to match your group by statement**:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, Business.Note> testData2 = groupedData.First().ToDictionary(g => g.Key);
```